# how to get name of a drawable assets dynamically in android?

Tags: android

I have some photos in my drawable folder res that name of them is like

- move1.jpg
- move2.jpg
- move3.jpg
  and so on.

I have a table in my database which has a field to store photo ID.

I have a selected list of items (in my case movement), that I want, user see the proper photo based on the Id of photo.

```
movements = db.getAllMovements(true);
...

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  Dialog movement_image_dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
  movement_image_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.image_dialog);

  ImageView movement_imageView = (ImageView) movement_image_dialog.findViewById(R.id.movement_imageview);

  **int photoId = finalMovements.get(position).getPhotoId();**
  **movement_imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.*move4*);**
...
}
```

My question is how I can set the Image resource with the photoId that I have?
I need something like this
**`R.drawalbe.(move+photoId)`**

Comment: means You want to set the Photo If User select the List Value as 2 then set Image as move+2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use resource `getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)` as

int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", this.getPackageName());

Where

**this** is an Activity.

**nameOfDrawable** is move1, move2 etc in your case.

drawableResourceId is the one you can pass in

`movement_imageView.setImageResource(drawableResourceId);`

Answer (score 1):

> we get dinamically images from like this.

```
String imageId=yourImageId;
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                      .getIdentifier(imageId, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this..

```
int photoId=R.drawable.move1;

img.setImageResource(photoId);
```